# Reading and Writing all JPEG metadata in Silverlight

Tags: c#, image, silverlight, metadata, exif

I've developed a Silverlight application that needs to compress JPEG images on the client. I've been using a library called [FJCore](https://code.google.com/p/fjcore/) to achieve this goal.

One of the biggest issues I'm encountering, however, is the fact that this toolkit requires you to convert the JPEG to a WriteableBitmap first which strips off all the metadata associated with the JPEG such as EXIF, XMP, JFIF, etc. I've modified the source of the FJCore library to persist the EXIF, compress the image, and then reattach the EXIF data. This process works but loses other types of metadata information.

Instead of having to implement a function that saves and writes each different type of metadata that exists for the JPEG format, I am looking for a simplified approach that will allow me to extract all metadata, regardless of type or format, use the FJCore toolkit to compress/resize that image, and then reattach all the previously saved metadata. Some direction or sample code that could help me achieve my goal would be greatly appreciated. Remember, this is a Silverlight application, so those .NET libraries are what I have to work with.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using FJCore aka ImageTools. All you need to do is add this on line 212:

```
// Exif.  Do something?
headers.Add(header);
```

https://github.com/briandonahue/FluxJpeg.Core/blob/master/FJCore/Decoder/JpegDecoder.cs

And make sure you copy those headers when resizing:

```
jpegOut = new DecodedJpeg(
    new ImageResizer(jpegIn.Image)
        .Resize(320, ResamplingFilters.NearestNeighbor),
    jpegIn.MetaHeaders); // Retain EXIF details
```

Recompile and you should be good to go.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing 18 months ago. But yeah, thanks for updating this issue for me. I probably should have done that myself. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! I am forking this library on GitHub now and merging my fixes (I have another). Hopefully everybody will benefit from these fixes soon. The GitHub fork has a Nuget package